# Slow USB 3 write speed

Tags: performance, usb-drive, io

Writing to my USB 3 thumb drive (SanDisk Extreme SDCZ80-064G-FFP) is very slow on Linux: 1 GB takes longer than 200s. Using Windows (dual-boot on the same computer), the same 1 GB file can be copied in about 8s. The stick is formatted in FAT (it came pre-preformatted and I didn't change it) and I would like to keep it this way since I am using it on Windows as well,

How can I fix it? What steps can I perform to diagnose what is causing this?

I am running Manjaro/Arch with kernel version 4.5.4-1.

**Edit:**
First of all: I realized that the drive is formatted in FAT (not in NTFS, as I originally stated in the question) when I tried to mount it with `-o big_writes`. Sorry for the mistake!

I am adding the outputs of the commands mentioned in the comments. I don't see a problem with any of these.

Output of `journalctl -f` when I connect the drive, mount it and write some data:

```
Mai 23 20:32:37 manjaro kernel: usb 2-6: USB disconnect, device number 7
Mai 23 20:32:39 manjaro dbus[608]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Avahi' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service'
Mai 23 20:32:39 manjaro dbus[608]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service not found.
Mai 23 20:32:41 manjaro kernel: usb 2-6: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Mai 23 20:32:41 manjaro kernel: usb-storage 2-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Mai 23 20:32:41 manjaro kernel: scsi host12: usb-storage 2-6:1.0
Mai 23 20:32:41 manjaro mtp-probe[3627]: checking bus 2, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6"
Mai 23 20:32:41 manjaro mtp-probe[3627]: bus: 2, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Mai 23 20:32:42 manjaro kernel: scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Extreme          0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Mai 23 20:32:42 manjaro kernel: sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] 122544516 512-byte logical blocks: (62.7 GB/58.4 GiB)
Mai 23 20:32:42 manjaro kernel: sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Mai 23 20:32:42 manjaro kernel: sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
Mai 23 20:32:42 manjaro kernel: sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Mai 23 20:32:42 manjaro kernel:  sdc: sdc1
Mai 23 20:32:42 manjaro kernel: sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Mai 23 20:32:43 manjaro dbus[608]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Avahi' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service'
Mai 23 20:32:43 manjaro dbus[608]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service not found.
Mai 23 20:32:52 manjaro sudo[3667]: user : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/
Mai 23 20:32:52 manjaro sudo[3667]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mai 23 20:32:52 manjaro sudo[3667]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mai 23 20:33:11 manjaro sudo[3676]: user : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/dd bs=1M count=1024 if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/test conv=fdatasync status=progress
Mai 23 20:33:11 manjaro sudo[3676]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mai 23 20:35:01 manjaro anacron[2235]: Job `cron.daily' started
Mai 23 20:35:03 manjaro anacron[2235]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Mai 23 20:35:45 manjaro sudo[3676]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Ouput of `dmesg`:

```
[ 2507.302345] usb 2-6: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 2507.317395] usb-storage 2-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2507.317758] scsi host12: usb-storage 2-6:1.0
[ 2508.319922] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Extreme          0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 2508.333123] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] 122544516 512-byte logical blocks: (62.7 GB/58.4 GiB)
[ 2508.333353] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 2508.333362] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[ 2508.333634] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 2508.346488]  sdc: sdc1
[ 2508.347918] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Commands used for mounting and writing:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/
$ sudo dd bs=1M count=1024 if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/test conv=fdatasync status=progress
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1,1 GB, 1,0 GiB) copied, 154,158 s, 7,0 MB/s
```

Output of `lsusb -t`:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 5000M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

**Edit 2:** I tried two other kernels: 4.4.11 and 4.6.0. Writing is still slow with both of them. Additionally, the problem seems to be related to the drive since I get higher transfer speeds (90 MB/s) for an external USB 3 hard disk.

**Edit 3:** I did some benchmarking on an Ubuntu 16.04 Live System. The results are way better (though still not very good):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/274D-D62C$ dd bs=1M count=1024 if=/dev/zero of=./test conv=fdatasync status=progress
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 12.2623 s, 87.6 MB/s
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/274D-D62C$ dd bs=1M count=1024 if=/dev/zero of=./test conv=fdatasync status=progress
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 64.5742 s, 16.6 MB/s
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/274D-D62C$ dd bs=1M count=1024 if=/dev/zero of=./test conv=fdatasync status=progress
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 83.6521 s, 12.8 MB/s
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/274D-D62C$ dd bs=1M count=1024 if=/dev/zero of=./test conv=fdatasync status=progress
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 21.842 s, 49.2 MB/s
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/274D-D62C$ dd bs=1M count=1024 if=/dev/zero of=./test conv=fdatasync status=progress
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 16.3149 s, 65.8 MB/s
```

**Edit 4:** I just tried it once more using a recent Arch/Manjaro kernel (4.11.1) and the result is a bit better: I get transfer speeds of about 10 MB/s (so ~100s for 1GB). This is, however, still much slower than Windows.

**Edit 5:** I finally found the time to come back to this issue. Running the current Manjaro kernel `Linux janmanjaro 5.4.74-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Nov 1 13:43:13 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, I get 15 - 30 MB/s (usually closer to 15 MB/s). Mounting with `sudo mount -o async,flush /dev/sdc1 /mnt/` (as suggested in [Extremely slow speed when writing to USB FAT32 drive in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/970594/extremely-slow-speed-when-writing-to-usb-fat32-drive-in-linux)) improves the speed by roughly 5 MB/s. This is till ridiculously slower than Windows and also much slower than Ubuntu.

I also ran `sudo fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=test.img --rw=randrw --size=500m --io_size=10g --blocksize=4k --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=1 --direct=1 --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reportin` as suggested by @Mikko Rantalainen. The results are:

```
Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=3444KiB/s (3527kB/s), 3444KiB/s-3444KiB/s (3527kB/s-3527kB/s), io=202MiB (212MB), run=60001-60001msec
   WRITE: bw=3432KiB/s (3514kB/s), 3432KiB/s-3432KiB/s (3514kB/s-3514kB/s), io=201MiB (211MB), run=60001-60001msec
```

I have not run this on Ubuntu yet.

Comment: Check the connection speed with `lsusb -t`. Your flash drive should show up as 5000M. If it's 480M, gen 2.0, then you have discovered your problem. If that's the case it could be a driver issue - have to check `dmesg` and `journalctl -xb` for any issues noted during initialization. The speed difference is far more than a file system config issue though - 200s+ is a throughput of about 5MB/sec - the 3.0 speeds you are seeing on windows are slow enough (125MB/sec out of a typical top end of ~300MB/s - theoretical top end of 500MB/s), assuming its not a budget type flash drive.

Comment: [Here](http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/machine-related/sandisk-extreme-64-usb-3-speed-test-benchmark-review) are some test with the same device. Works fine for that guy... I don't see anything wrong in your journal so not sure what to say... You may as well try an older kernel see if it makes any difference...

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no better answer, I just wanted to remark that your values are very good for a flash drive in general, and quite within the expected range for your specific flash drive.

Marketing values such as 190MB/s write speed are not in general sustainable (they are valid for a few seconds at most, till the internal buffer is filled, and do not reflect actual flash performance) and only are true for sequential writes. As soon as a filesystem is involved, speed considerably degrades. Random access write speeds are often <1MB/s even on high-grade fast USB drives, so just a few random writes (as filesystems commonly require) can destroy write performance.

You can try to use a more flash friendly file system such as f2fs (a 4.4 or newer kernel is recommended), which do a good job at reducing randomw rites, to see if that helps.

Comment: I am aware that marketing values are not accurate. The actual questions, however, are: why is linux SO MUCH slower than Windows and why is the Ubuntu kernel (though still slower than Windows) faster than the Arch/Manjaro kernel?

Comment: You may find Ubuntu mounts removable media with an option to flush writes aggressively so as to avoid you losing data if you yank a key out without unmounting it first. See https://superuser.com/questions/970594/extremely-slow-speed-when-writing-to-usb-fat32-drive-in-linux which seems to be the same question.

Comment: Works for me, I had 20kbs on msdos filesystem on usb 3.0 (which was default when I've bought my Pendrive) . Ext4 did the job

Comment: @Anon: Thanks for the hint but it does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need FAT? In my experience, Linux implementation of FAT driver seems to access the device with a sequence that causes some devices to have really poor performance. I have seen 10x performance improvement from some flash devices when formatted as ext4 instead.

Considering that the link you provided in comments (http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/machine-related/sandisk-extreme-64-usb-3-speed-test-benchmark-review) was testing read and write speeds without partitions, it might be that your flash device has poor performance when accessed by linux FAT driver. If that's true, it should also have bad random IO performance in general.

---

You can test the device performance with `fio`. Change to some directory inside the device you want to test and run following command to test performance with mixed random 4k read/write performance:

```
fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=test.img --rw=randrw --size=500m --io_size=10g --blocksize=4k --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=1 --direct=1 --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting
```

That creates 500 MB test file called `test.img` and then starts to read and write in random 4 KB blocks with queue depth of 1. Increase the `size` in case your device has a huge internal cache. This test has maximum runtime of 60 seconds. Consider this the worst case scenario with your device. A pretty fast flash device (Intel SSD 910) gets following results here:

```
...
read : io=1041.4MB, bw=17773KB/s, iops=4443, runt= 60001msec
...
write: io=1038.5MB, bw=17723KB/s, iops=4430, runt= 60001msec
...
```

To test the best case you can increase the blocksize and do 
2 paraller processes with iodepth=32:

```
fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=test.img --rw=randrw --size=500m --io_size=10g --blocksize=512k --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=32 --direct=1 --numjobs=2 --runtime=60 --group_reporting
```

A pretty fast flash device (Intel SSD 910) gets following results here:

```
...
read : io=10892MB, bw=457088KB/s, iops=892, runt= 24401msec
...
write: io=9588.0MB, bw=402365KB/s, iops=785, runt= 24401msec
...
```

Of course, if you really want high scores, you should do sequential reading with high iodepth. This should be near the numbers you see in the device spec sheets (that is, never in real life):

```
fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=test.img --rw=read --size=500m --io_size=10g --blocksize=512k --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=32 --direct=1 --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting
```

A pretty fast flash device (Intel SSD 910) gets following results here:

```
...
read : io=10240MB, bw=1468.8MB/s, iops=2937, runt=  6972msec
...
```

Note that this falls short from spec sheet (around 2 GB/s) because I have configured I/O scheduler lowest possible latency (`deadline` I/O scheduler with `1 > ../queue/iosched/fifo_batch` and `50 > ../queue/iosched/read_expire`).

Note the huge difference between worst case scenario (around 17 MB/s) and best case scenario (around 1470 MB/s).

Comment: Note that the above is "worst case" in meaning that drive internal RAM caching is still allowed. Add `--sync` to each `fio` command line flags to see the actual worst case performance the device may have. Less than 1% of the best case scenario are common here!

Answer (score 3):

I'll offer you a crumb of hope here.  I'm looking at UHS-II SD-cards and USB readers and observe the following from the Ubuntu "Disks" applet benchmarking tab:

- Ubuntu 14.04 - kernel 4.4 - read ~140MB/s, write ~50MB/s
- Ubuntu 17.04 - kernel 4.10 - read ~270MB/s write ~200MB/s

These use the traditional "usb mass-storage driver".  Something has changed in the kernel between these two points that accelerates the mass-storage driver.

Usual comments re-benchmarking apply, however our in-house application achieves about 10% faster than the benchmarked times so they're a pretty good representation of many use-cases.

USB external hard disks may actually use an alternate driver to the generic mass-storage driver so you can't always compare them directly.

Comment: I can verify that with Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 4.4.0, trying to zero out my SanDisk 128G USB3 flash drive I get around 40MB/s. Honestly it jumps around from as low as 10MB/s to 55MB/s. I'm running "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=50M". I tried using 75M, 100M and others, they all have the same behavior. As far as raw reads, I am seeing consistent 105MB/s: "sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/null bs=150M"

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Linux uses a 4k block size for disks (windows does this too for ntfs) which is ok for hard drives which have a sector size 512bytes but is no good for flash drives which have an erase block size of 128KB.  I guess that operating this way would cause 1 write of 128KB to actually take 32 (128/4) writes resulting in 1/32th the performance.  This level of performance is consistent with your measured performance on linux vs. windows.

Please read http://linux-howto-guide.blogspot.com/2009/10/increase-usb-flash-drive-write-speed.html.  The solution presented is to manually specify the "disk geometry" to have a block size of 128KB.  Of course, the flash drive doesn't even have a "disk geometry" like mechanical hard drives do but whatever.  This still an inperfect solution though because any files that are less than 128KB in size will use a full 128KB on the flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit dated, but

I was frustrated to the extreme backing up a ubuntu server 20.04 to a 12T Seagate expansion drive over USB 3. Transfer speeds were reported in kilobytes more often than not. and every 20 or so seconds everything would stall for 10 to 15 seconds. Some sort of cache write, I suspect.

Solutions? I tried more than a few from around the web over recent months, including changing the NTFS format to ext4, mucking around with cache settings, changing cables, etc etc. If you're affected I'm sure you've been there.  Nothing helped.

**Yesterday I ripped the HDD out of the case. It was labelled a Barracuda.
I placed the disk into a USB 3 docking stating on my desktop PC and initiated an rsync backup over the LAN. Bingo - great continuous xfer speeds**

I'm led to conclude that the issue is the controller in the Seagate expansion case, not Linux. That the Expansion HDD performed well when plugged into Windows 10 suggests that it may also be optimised for that system.

I've now moved the docking station onto a USB 3 port on the Ubuntu server, where it's currently backing up at ~50MB/s

I can live with that.

Comment: This seems unrelated o the question at hand, which is about slow USB transfer speeds.